# my app crashes whenever this activity starts

Tags: android, sql, json

I am trying to make an app which works with online databases, I have checked all php's are working fine so no error from the server side, but whenever this part of my activity starts the app crashes and again goes to previous page.

```
package hp.bunk.com.bunk;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class displaybunk extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    String y, n, m, t;
    Button b1, b2, b3;
    String url = "URL OF PHP";
    TextView y1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yes);
    TextView m1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.majority);
    TextView n1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.no);
    TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.details);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String id;
    Boolean vie;
    String url1= "URL OF PHP";
    String url2 = "URL OF PHP";
    String url3 = "URL OF PHP";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_displaybunk);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
        b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);
        b3.setOnClickListener(this);
        if (extras != null) {
            id = extras.getString("new_variable_name");
        }
        RelativeLayout re = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative);
        SharedPreferences sha1 = getSharedPreferences("bunks.com.android",MODE_PRIVATE);
        vie = sha1.getBoolean(id,false);

        if (vie == true){

            re.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"you have already voted ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                    y = object.getString("yes");
                    m = object.getString("depend");
                    n = object.getString("no");
                    t = object.getString("yes");
                    t1.setText(t);
                    n1.setText(n);
                    m1.setText(m);
                    y1.setText(y);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                return super.getParams();
            }
        };

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.button6:
                Intent intent = getIntent();

                SharedPreferences sha = getSharedPreferences("bunks.com.android", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sha.edit();
                edit.putBoolean(id, true);
                edit.commit();
                RequestQueue requestqueue = new Volley().newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

                StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url1, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            if (jsonObject.names().get(0).equals("Sucess")) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your Vote has been Counted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                }) {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        HashMap<String, String> re = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        re.put("id", id);

                        return re;
                    }
                };
                requestqueue.add(request);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.button7:
                Intent intent1 = getIntent();
                SharedPreferences sha1 = getSharedPreferences("bunks.com.android", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor edit1 = sha1.edit();
                edit1.putBoolean(id, true);
                edit1.commit();
                RequestQueue requestqueue1 = new Volley().newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

                StringRequest request1 = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url2, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            if (jsonObject.names().get(0).equals("Sucess")) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Vote has been Counted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                }) {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        HashMap<String, String> re = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        re.put("id", id);

                        return re;
                    }
                };
                requestqueue1.add(request1);

                finish();
                startActivity(intent1);
                break;
            case R.id.button8:
                Intent intent2 = getIntent();
                SharedPreferences sha2 = getSharedPreferences("bunks.com.android",MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor edit2 = sha2.edit();
                edit2.putBoolean(id,true);
                edit2.commit();
                RequestQueue requestqueue2 = new Volley().newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

                StringRequest request2 = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url3, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            if (jsonObject.names().get(0).equals("Sucess")) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Vote has been Counted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                }) {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        HashMap<String, String> re = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        re.put("id", id);

                        return re;
                    }
                };
                requestqueue2.add(request2);


                finish();
                startActivity(intent2);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

and also here is my log file:

```
04-07 01:23:01.329 11852-11852/hp.bunk.com.bunk D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
04-07 01:23:03.229 11852-11852/hp.bunk.com.bunk E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
04-07 01:28:11.289 11852-11852/hp.bunk.com.bunk E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
04-07 01:28:16.869 11852-11852/hp.bunk.com.bunk D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-07 01:28:16.869 11852-11852/hp.bunk.com.bunk W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418b8da0)
04-07 01:28:16.879 11852-11852/hp.bunk.com.bunk E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: hp.bunk.com.bunk, PID: 11852
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{hp.bunk.com.bunk/hp.bunk.com.bunk.displaybunk}: java.lang.NullPointerException
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2313)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2500)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:171)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5679)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:68)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:145)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:28)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:42)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:186)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:168)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:508)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:180)
      at hp.bunk.com.bunk.displaybunk.<init>(displaybunk.java:31)
      at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
      at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2304)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2500) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:171) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5679) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107) 
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: [Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can't call getFindById in the class constructor like you are doing now:

```
TextView y1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yes);
TextView m1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.majority);
TextView n1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.no);
TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.details);
```

You have to wait until after the views have been inflated during onCreate(), so move these calls to findViewById() to that point.

Comment: thanks for reply...i change the code..it's still crashing..!! :)

Comment: please update your question with the change suggested by @Doug Stevenson

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution... Bundle extras; they should be initialized after onCreate().. btw thanks @Doug Stevenson